# Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]?

Tags: transactions, nonce

i have this address 0xb5f82127b5067f1019abd362ba812c0ef8196717
as you can see i have 3 transaction failed with this error :

`Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]`.

[image: Ethereum Transaction Failed/Cancelled]

I was trying to send from my ledger live to this contract address 0x6d477D2906ad181a4975ACfd40366a8808914073.

I do search for similar error everybody talk about resending the transaction with higher fee with the same nonce but regarding to this [Canceling or Replacing a Transaction After it’s Been Sent](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/transactions/checking-or-replacing-a-tx-after-sending/) they say :

If you see a red ( ! ) symbol, or a “BAD INSTRUCTION” or “OUT OF GAS” error message, it means that the transaction was not successfully sent. **You cannot cancel or replace this transaction**. Instead, **send a new transaction**. If you received an “Out of Gas” error, you should double the gas limit you specified originally.

I try to resend the same transaction with the same sender, receiver and nonce with zero amount using metamask but **nonce to low error** appear.

My questions :

1 - Can I resend the transaction with higher gas limit (using the same nonce),knowing that i already have 3 failed transaction from nonce 0 to 2?if yes how, in this **situation**?

2 - What happened to the ETH? if the transaction is failed why i can't see the amount in the wallet?

3 - It their any problem related to ledger live it self in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The txs you're talking about happened about 2 and a half years ago, isnt it a little late to worry about them?
to answer your questions :

1 - No, when a transaction is sent, the account nonce increments once its mined, whether it succeeds or fails. just send the next tx with nonce = 3

2 - huh? Your ETH should definitely be still there

3 - No, the error probably comes from this bit of code.

```
if (!parentAddress.call.value(msg.value)(msg.data))
      throw;
```

which throws ( `throw` is more or less an analogue for `revert` except it sucks, it doesnt let you provide set an error message, and eats all your gas, it isnt used anymore and im pretty sure it acutally has been removed from the latest solidity versions) if the forwarded call isnt successful.

What id try to do is send another tx (with nonce = 3) to this contract with a bigger amount of gas, if it still gives the same error then my theory is right and theres really not much you can do about it, it just wont work at all

Comment: Yes i think is to late.
Thank you for the clarification.